# Where to put "extra" implementation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c-category

Occationaly I see snippets of code creating new methods for objects and such that looks like this:

```
@implementation UIImage (Extras)

- (void)aMethod:(id)anObject {
  // some functionality
}

@end
```

Where do I put this code? Do I put it in the class I'm currently writing code for? If so at what point in the code do I need to put this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put this *category* code whereever you like. In general, this code should be in a file called **UIImage+Extras.m** and a matching header file **UIImage+Extras.h**.

Comment: Thanks guys... so just add it to those files and import it as normal? :) simple as that? brilliant.

Comment: I wonder about the value of this common idiom. Why not just put your methods in a helper class called UIImageExtras with _no category_. What does the category buy you other than saving importing your helper class? The downside of the category is clear: if your addition is a common name you risk running into a collision with a future change in the UIImage class, or, more likely, with someone else's similar category when you include their library (because they read the same post on SO). What's the big advantage that I'm missing?

Comment: It's an elegant approach. You can call methods directly on the object. Helper classes are nothing more than containers for what should be static functions. They are ok, but take away lots of the charm from object oriented programming. My take here: if you are working *on* an object, use category, if you are working *with* an object, use a helper class. And categories work very well with subclasses, too. As for name collisions, it may be a  good idea to prefix your methods names.

Answer (score 1):

This is an Objective-C feature known as a "category". See these articles for more info:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html
- http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity and to keep code clean I usually put class categories in separate files.

But in general I think you just need to declare your category in some header and import it to let compiler know about methods you add. Implementation of those methods can be put in any (implementation) file, but once again I think it is better to keep it in separate place.